# Group timestamp by shifted day range

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with an integer field called `amount` and a timestamp field. Now I want to group the fields in this table by a certain timestamp interval. Namely, between 12:00 (12pm) and 12:00 of the next day. How can I do this?

E.g., I want to calculate the sum of the `amount` per this timestamp interval:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM TABLE GROUP BY INTERVAL
```

Comment: Please provide table definition (ddl),  sample data ( as text - **no images**), and the expected results of that data. As your description indicates a date range I suggest your test data cover multiple (3) days, and times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offset the grouping expression by 12 hours and cast it as `date`.
Provided that the timestamp field of `the_table` is called `ts` then:

```sql
select
    (ts + interval '12 hours')::date - 1 as d,
    sum(amount) as s
from the_table
group by (ts + interval '12 hours')::date
order by d;
```